# Not getting checkbox value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm loading a PHP page with checked and unchecked boxes. When submitting the form and using the `$_POST` method to get the value of the array, the value of every checkbox in `isReadOnly[]` array is "0", even when the box is checked.

I KNOW THAT MY CODE HAS SOME ISSUES WITH INTERPOLATION. PLEASE DO NOT COMMENT ON THAT.

```
<?php
$departmentID = $_GET['departmentID'];
$departID = $_POST['employees'];
$isReadOnly = $_POST['isReadOnly'];

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   

  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof ($departID);$i++) {


$result3 = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO userDepartment (userID, departmentID,isReadOnly) SELECT userID,'" . $departID[$i] . "'," . $isReadOnly[$i] . " FROM users where userID='$id'");

        }
}


?>

SOME OTHER CODE...

<?php

$sql = "SELECT d.departmentID, d.departmentName, ud.departmentID, ud.isReadOnly FROM department d LEFT JOIN userDepartment ud ON ud.departmentID = d.departmentID AND ud.userID = '$id' ORDER BY d.departmentID ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

 $c = 0;

echo "<div class='manageUserTable'> 
        <table><th colspan='2'>Budget</th><th>Is Read Only</th>\n";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $departID = $row[2];

    $checkedDep = ($row[0] == $departID) ? 'checked="checked"':'';


    $checkedreadOnly = ($row[3] == '1') ? 'checked="checked"':'';

echo "<tr>
    <td class='check'><input type='checkbox' name='employees[$c]' value='".$row['0']. "' " . $checkedDep . "'></td>
    <td class='depName'>".$row['1']."</td>
    <td class='check'><input type='hidden' name='isReadOnly[$c]' value='0'><input type='checkbox' name='isReadOnly[$c]' value='".$row['3']. "' " . $checkedreadOnly . "'>                                       
 </tr>";

  $c++;
}
echo "</table></div>\n";

?>
```

This is the `var_dump` of `$_POST`:

```
array(5) { ["username"]=> string(15) "bobby.zimmerman" ["employees"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["isReadOnly"]=> array(29) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" [7]=> string(1) "0" [8]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(1) "0" [10]=> string(1) "0" [11]=> string(1) "0" [12]=> string(1) "0" [13]=> string(1) "0" [14]=> string(1) "0" [15]=> string(1) "0" [16]=> string(1) "0" [17]=> string(1) "0" [18]=> string(1) "0" [19]=> string(1) "0" [20]=> string(1) "0" [21]=> string(1) "0" [22]=> string(1) "0" [23]=> string(1) "0" [24]=> string(1) "0" [25]=> string(1) "0" [26]=> string(1) "0" [27]=> string(1) "0" [28]=> string(1) "0" } ["id"]=> string(2) "82" ["update"]=> string(14) "Update Account" }
```

Index 0 of `isReadOnly[]` should have been "1" in this output.

Comment: You have the hidden and non hidden fields names the same. That could be causing a problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @JasonK it doesn't appear that changing the name made a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: CAn your post your form?

Comment: The form is in the bottom php of the post. It starts with the echo below the $c variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `<input type='checkbox' name='isReadOnly[$c]' value='".$row['3']. "' " . $checkedreadOnly . "'>`, `value='".$row['3']. "'` should have been `value='1'`.